# Campo de contraseña en modelos Django

Tags: python, django, formularios, django-models, contraseña

Cree un modelo para los usuarios, y utilizo mis modelos para crear formularios, el caso es que el espacio que corresponde a contraseña no quiero que se muestre lo que el usuario esta escribiendo.

```
class usuario (models.Model):
    ID_Usuario = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    Nombre_Usuario = models.CharField(max_length= 15, blank= False, null= False)
    Contraseña  = models.CharField(max_length= 20, blank= False, null= False)
    Tipo_Usuario = models.CharField(max_length= 20, blank= False, null= False)

    def __integer__(self):
        return self.ID_Usuario

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['ID_Usuario']
        verbose_name = 'Usuario'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Usuarios'
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como hago para que oculte la contraseña que el usuario esta escribiendo

Comment: Las contraseñas nunca deben ir como un charfield en una base de datos, por motivos de seguridad de tu aplicación y de los usuarios que la ocupan. 
Te recomiendo utilizar el modelo [django.contrib.auth.models.User](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#user-objects) que posee el campo password el cual se almacena hasheado y provee los métodos de autenticación y cambio de contraseña necesarios. En el mediano plazo, te darás cuenta que vale la pena usar este. Los docs proveen [tutoriales](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/) para lo que requieres.

Answer (score 0):

En tu archivo `forms` puedes hacer la personalización de la siguiente forma:

```
password1 = forms.CharField(label="Password", widget=forms.PasswordInput, strip=False)
```

Ten en cuenta que django ya provee elementos que suplen lo que quieres hacer

```
django.contrib.auth.models.User
```

Puedes crear un modelo que herede de esta clase